# Downloading songs from external hard dirve

Tags: itunes

I'm using an external hard drive to download songs to itunes.  When I'm done syncing, I get a message saying my ipod cannot be ejected because some of the files are being used by another source.  Somehow I think some of the files from the external hard drive got downloaded onto the internal hard drive.  I'm not super computer literate but I really don't remember doing anything other than moving the file from the external hard drive to iTunes.  Why is this happening and what do I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the music to iTunes to put on your phone, you're importing it into iTunes. If you import music into iTunes, it will get stored on your internal HD. ITunes has its own folders on your computer containing all of your files.